# Print Json data in html tabel by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

[image]I have JSON data saved in this api `https://api.myjson.com/bins/xeza2`. I want to print the data in a table by using only JavaScript or jQuery. I have tried a few things. I have used XMLHTTP request. Json.parse() . Every method on stack. 
This was the first thing I have tried

```
$(function () {

   var people = [];

   $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/xeza2', function (data) {
      $.each(data.info, function (i, f) {
         var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.id + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + "</td>" + "</tr>"
         $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
      });

   });

});
```

Comment: 'I have tried everything I could'. Can you elaborate on this? Or provide some code?

Comment: i have added the js code i got on stack.

Comment: And what is not working in the above code? Are you getting any error?

Comment: So what is the error? What do you see when you console.log()? Debug it

Comment: my code is not coming inside $.each

Comment: @RitikSingh See my answer. `data.info` is undefined you need to use `data.ct_info`

Comment: @MattCroak is right, you have to use `data.ct_info`, tested it , data is coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.info` is `undefined` hence why you weren't getting anything added to the table. You need to change it to `data.ct_info`.

The below code can access the JSON data in your request's response and appends it to the table. I am not sure how you want the data to look or what properties you are trying to access (hence the `undefined`'s) that I'll leave up to you but the below should help get you started.

`f.job` and `f.roll` are non-existent properties.

```js
$(function() {

  var people = [];
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/xeza2', function(data) {
    $.each(data.ct_info, function(i, f) {

      var tblRow = "<tr>" + `<td id=${f.id}>` + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "</tr>"
      $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

      var users = []

      //GET USER INFO
      f.Qid_info.forEach((x) => {
        x.user_info.forEach((y) => {
          //avoid duplicates
          var foundUser = users.find((user) => {
            return user.id === y.id
          })
          if (!foundUser) {
            users.push(y)
          }
        })
      })

      $.each(users, function(i, user) {
        var userRow = "<tr>" + `<td id=${user.id}>` + "User's Name:" +
          "</td>" +
          "<td>" + user.name + "</td>" + "</tr>"
        $(userRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
      })

    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='userdata'>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes.... @Matt I got the solution from your answer. And it worked. I don't know who downvoted it.

Comment: can you help me how would i print Qid_info array in json

Comment: I updated the snippet to get you all of the user info. Again I am not sure how you want it to look but you just need to read your data better to see what properties you are getting back. Also, since my original answer answered your original question I don't see why it has been unselected as the answer for this post.

Comment: To be more clear I have updated a pic on how i want to print data in table.